# Display card when clicking a marker google maps AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

**UPDATED**

I want to display a customized card (Ionic card), whenever I click on a marker in google maps angularjs.

I managed to call the infoWindow, but I don't know how to change its input to add the card.

Here is my code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
        lat: markers[0].lat,
        lng: markers[0].lng
    },
    map: this.map,
    title: markers[0].title,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: icon1
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

marker.content = 'marker.description';

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(marker.content);
    infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add the listener on the marker instead of the map. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple?hl=fr

Comment: Thanx for the doc.